# Will it notify my mom if I turn off find my iPhone?

Tags: find-my-iphone

my email is my apple id so if it sent a email to my apple id that is ok, but i want to know if the person who pays for my phone, my mom, will get a notification. Please help.

Comment: Your question does not make sense from beginning to end. Are you in the same family (iCloud > Family) as your mother? Is the iCloud Apple ID your mother's, or is it yours? Does your mother have access to your email address? I do not think of a way, other than these three, that your mother could receive a Find my iPhone notification (paying for a phone is just payment, there is no record of the payer on the phone).

Answer (score 1):

No, if your email is setup on your iPhone and someone sends you an email, your mom will not be notified.